# bacbkone router redirect if not authenticated

Tags: backbone.js, routes, marionette

I am trying to implement a simple app that needs a login and user authentication. As I am new to backbone and marionette, I have been trying to follow the example for this tutorial: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction

Generally I have set up a new app:

```
var App = new Marionette.Application({});

App.addRegions({
    headerRegion : "#nav-region",
    mainRegion : "#main-region"
});

App.navigate = function(route,  options){
    options || (options = {});
    Backbone.history.navigate(route, options);
};

App.getCurrentRoute = function(){
   return Backbone.history.fragment
};

App.on("start", function(){
    if(Backbone.history){
       Backbone.history.start();
    }
});
```

And routers are defined in modules, e.g.:

```
App.module("ContentManagementApp", function(ContentManagementApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){
    ContentManagementApp.Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        appRoutes : {
            "contentmanagement/:dsid(/:dspageclassid)": "showContentMananagement",
        }
    });

    var API = {
        showContentMananagement : function(dsid, dspageclassid){
            // If not set, set to frontpage
            ContentManagementApp.Show.Controller.showDSPage(dsid, dspageclassid);
            App.execute("set:active:header", "contentmanagement");
        },
    };

    App.on("contentmanagement:show", function(dsid, dspageclassid){
        App.navigate("contentmanagement/" + dsid + "/" + dspageclassid);
        API.showContentMananagement(dsid, dspageclassid);
    });

    App.addInitializer(function(){
        new ContentManagementApp.Router({
        controller : API
        });
    });
});
```

I would like to test if the user is logged and redirect to the login page when the app starts, but it seems like App.addInitializer is called before. Does it mean I have to do the check in each module, or can I get by it somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you determine if the user is logged or not?

If it's a call to an API that could fail (due to the user being unauthenticated), it will probably return an HTTP error code 403. I usually do this using a global jQuery `ajax.error()` handler, I check if it's a 403 (Forbidden) for any of my normal API calls (model fetching and so on) and if it is, I redirect to a login url.

Otherwise, if you want to check for a cookie or similar, you should do it before calling `Backbone.history.start()`. Only start the app if the user is logged. :)

Comment: i was planning to store the access token in a cookie, so something like

    if(Backbone.history){
       var t = utils.readCookie("cookie");
       if(t == null){
          this.trigger("login:show");
       }
       else {
          Backbone.history.start();
       }...

Comment: yep, then check for that on your cookie just before calling app.start()

Answer (score 0):

I just set this up in my app - in your backend when the user is logged in create a cookie/destroy it when they sign-out. Then I use the [jquery-cookie-rails](https://github.com/RyanScottLewis/jquery-cookie-rails) gem to access the cookie as $.cookie('cookie_name') and if it isn't there I route them to the signin path.

I would note - I also check to see if the user is signed on the backend when hitting different controller actions and route them appropriately. I just like the extra protection :).